# What is the meaning of primes here?

Tags: geometry

I'm reading Aarts: "Plane and solid geometry", here: He mentions "primes" but he didn't define it in the book.

> [image]

I guess he's referring to the non-quadratic terms. But I want to be sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primes are the apostrophe signs, i.e. $x'$ is pronounced "x prime."

Comment: Oh, in Portuguese,  they call it "linha' (line). I always thought it would be "x line" in English.

Comment: I'm not English either, so I also find it a little funny. In Denmark we would say "x mærke," which would be translated to "x mark" or "x tick."